# How to create a Video player using openGL

Tags: opengl, video, rendering, video-player

I'm having a custom video decoder. To this decoder, whenever i give an `H.264` file (only video element not audio) as an input, i get a set of `YUV` frames as my output. I then convert this `YUV` frames to `RGB24` frames and render it in `OpenGL`. This conversion and rendering happens simultaneously i.e. frame by frame thereby giving a look like as if i'm viewing a video.

Once i have done the above, my next task is to implement other features like play, pause, step backward, step forward, etc.

Currently i'm just rendering the frames as and how it gets decoded and converted to RGB. That is the frame rate is around 60-70 fps. Now if i have to implement this play/pause functionality, then how should i proceed. That is if pause is pressed, the decoder should wait till i press play button.

Provide some solutions for the same.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is sort of strange that you managed to do so much and got stuck at this point of your project. If you run an OpenGL program I assume you have some infinite loop in which you capture all events (mouse, keys) as well as read images from your file and render them to the screen (using OpenGL). This sort of application is typically run in a multi-thread environment though, specially the reading of the file. You probably want to have some buffer in which you always store something like the next second of animation of so (or more), and when you exec the event loop your read from that buffer. Meanwhile, while you read stuff from the buffer, the thread the reads the data from disk needs to fill up the buffer with new information.

This could be using a producer-consumer algorithm. Note though that you don't need to do this in a multithreading environment but you may have continuity problems if your system can't run at 30 fps say. In the event loop, you can read say the next 20 frames or 10 or whatever, then read the next image from the buffer, render, etc.

In this loop if the viewer has pushed the pause key (say space) then simply pass the reading of the file and the render to screen tasks in the loop. Alternatively you can read the entire file to memory before you render it.

```
// event loop
 while (1) {
    char key = nextEvent(...)
    if (key == 'x') quiteApp();
    else if (key == 'p') { pauseApp = (pauseApp == true) ? false : true; }
    if (!pauseApp) {
        // adjust the number of frames your read in each loop depending
        // on your frame rate. If you frame rate drops below 30 fps
        // read less frames, etc.
        readFrames(&buffer, videoFile, 10);
        getNextFrameFromBuffer(buffer, frameBuffer);
        displayFrameuBuffer(frameCount, frameBuffer);
    }
    frameCount++;
    // do time synchronisation here so that you always play at given frame
    // rate which is likely to be 30 fps.
    ...
}
```